# Gaps in Java knowledge but can't find the direction to search

Tags: java, android, class, scoping

===================================================================================================

**UPDATE:**

My problem was that I did not know that classes can indeed communicate with each other.  For example, you can create 2 classes, instantiate an object of each class in your program, and then actually pass one object into the other.  This not only directly solved my problem, it opens an entire world of possibilities for the future.

```
public class FirstClass {
    int valueToPass = 100;
    void methodToPass(){
    //do stuff
    return;
    }
}
public class SecondClass {
    FirstClass passedInObject;
    int valueFromOtherClass = passedObject.valueToPass;
    return;
    }
}
```

===================================================================================================

I understand a class is a blueprint of attributes and actions that can be instantiated as an object.
I understand an inner class is a non static class defined within another class and has access to the outer class' data.
I understand a child class is a separate file defining a class that does not have access to its parent's data.

So I've got my main activity class of an Android application.  I'm just making a simple dice game to help tie up all the loose ends.  I've defined the follow child classes in separate .java files:

Dice
ScoreCard

I instantiate an array of 5 Dice objects and 1 ScoreCard object and attach those objects to a "view" in the android OS's window, then assign an action method to that view with the set click listener method inside the object.  The objects work flawlessly.  I can click the dice and they will hold and unhold themselves, roll, and update their own views.  I can of course access the value of the dice from my main class by referencing their object.value variable.  (I understand that accessors are presumed by many to be superior to directly interacting directly with a child class' variables, this app is just to solidify conceptual ideas of the overall flow of an application) I can click a slot on the scoresheet and it will toggle the highlight that slot as the slot to assign the score to.  The scorecard object also updates the entire scorecard on the screen after each interaction.

So far so good, everything is working great, and I understand everything that is going on.

However, in my main activity class, I now want to create a roll function, and assign that function to the click listener for the roll button.  That works, however, when assigning a function to the click listener, you can not reference any non final variables because the click listener of a given view actually instantiates an anonymous object (anonymous class?) of the View class and overrides the onclick method with its own, therefore you can not reference any non final variables from an inner class defined in another method.  In other words, you can't pass the function you assign to the click listener any values from your main class, and although I do not understand why, the roll function I created can not access the main class' variables directly.

There is the first gap in my knowledge, and I've read dozens of tutorials, watched dozen's of videos, but I don't know why my roll function can't see the variables.

```
public mainclass extends otherclass {
      @override 
      otherclass.method {
             // where my application starts
             int a=7;
             roll();
      }

      void roll(){
          int funcVar = a;
          return;
      {
}
```

Eclipse says that a can not be resolved.

I try to make a public thinking that might allow the function to see it, but if I change

```
int a=7;
```

to

```
public int a=7;
```

then Eclipse says that it can't be public, only final.

A way around this is to create a new child class called Roll, or perhaps ActionButton to use it for other buttons in the future, just as I did with the ScoreCard and Dice classes.  This works great, in so far as I can instantiate a roll button object, assign a view to the object and then set the click listener to one of the object's methods.  However, this transfers the functionality of my rollbutton from my MainActivity class to my RollButton class, which doesn't have access to the data in my dice and scorecard objects.  In other words, I can't figure out how to make my child classes talk to each other, I don't really think they are even supposed to.  I imagine the main class is supposed to access each child class independently, but if that's the case then I'm not really sure what I'm supposed to do at this point.

The only solution I can think of is to put all those child classes into the same child class, DiceGame, and pretty much just use the MainActivity class to instantiate an object of the DiceGame class and transfer processing entirely over to that object.  While that would work, all the methods in the class would have access to all the data in the class, it seems to contradict the entire purpose of object oriented programming.

Is this all so messed up because of the way the click listener in android apps is assigned through instantiating an anonymous inner class that can't access any non final variables, or I just missing a key concept in the way Java applications are structured?

I'm sorry this is so long, but I really couldn't shorten it and still convey the entire problem.

-------edit----------

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public int a=7;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            // my application starts here

    Dice[] gameDice = new Dice[6];

    for (int i=1;i<6;i++) gameDice[i]= new Dice();
    for (int i = 1; i<6 ; i++){
        gameDice[i].dieView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.die1 + (i-1));
        gameDice[i].setListener();
    }


    int[] slotId = new int[] {R.id.val1,
            R.id.val1,R.id.val2,R.id.val3,R.id.val4,R.id.val5,
            R.id.val6,R.id.valsubtotal,R.id.valbonus,

            R.id.val3k,R.id.val4k,R.id.val5k,R.id.valfh,
            R.id.valsmstr,R.id.valstr,R.id.valdicey,R.id.valtotal
    };


    ScoreCard scoreCard = new ScoreCard();
    scoreCard.NUMBER_OF_SLOTS = slotId.length;
    for (int i=1 ; i<scoreCard.NUMBER_OF_SLOTS ; i++){
        scoreCard.slotView[i]=(TextView) findViewById(slotId[i]);
        if (i!=8 && i!=15) scoreCard.setListener(i);
    }
    scoreCard.initScoreCard();


    rollButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            roll();

        }
    });
}// end of overridden method

void roll(){
//do stuff
int funcVar = a; // can totally see a now that it is higher scope
return;
}
```

}//end of class

The suggestion to increase the scope of a did in fact work.  However, a is just an example I was using for simplicity's sake.  I really need to access those data contained in the objects I instantiated, and if I instantiate them in a higher scope the application abruptly ends upon launch.

Comment: It seems you do not understand the phrase "variable scoping".  If you declare 'public int a;' in the class immediately after 'public mainclass extends otherclass {', then it will work fine.  The way you have it now, 'a' only lives in the scope of the otherclass.method function.  You want the 'a' to live in the scope of the object instance.

Comment: This seems like a good link on "variable scoping" rules: http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html

Comment: make your variable as member of a class, i.e. declare it outside of the function.

Comment: Declaring a in the scope of the object instance does allow it to be seen by the roll(); function, but a was just a simple example, is that where I would wan't to instantiate all my objects as well, as it is the dice objects and scorecard objects that I would like the roll function to be able to interact with.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the confusion is between a variable and a field. A field is a property that is associated with an object. A variable exists only in the context of a method. When the method finishes, the variable vanishes.

A field, on the other hand, looks exactly the same as a variable except that a field is declared outside of any method, directly on the class "body". Fields and methods are declared at the same hierarchical level. You can see that on Eclipse. Check the "outline" view.

If you need several methods to read and write the same "variable", then what you need is a field. I hope this clarifies.

Comment: Others have suggested declaring the variable a in the higher scope of the main object, instead of the overridden object where the Android application initiates.  For the unused variable a that I used a merely an example to explain the problem I am having attaching the click event of the roll button to the data possessed by the instantiated scorecard and dice objects, the program does indeed compile without error.  Yet, when I move my object instantiations up to that scope the program compiles but crashes.

Comment: I think you need to provide an SSCCE (http://sscce.org/). Your problem seems to be more broad than what you have described here. Sorry for the negative answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Variables can have different scopes**:

```
public class MyClass {

   static int a; // variable bound to class MyClass, seen from all instances
   int b; // variable bound to instance, each instance of MyClass has its own value

   public void foo(int c) { // parameter variable: local
      int d; // local variable
   }
}
```

**Local variables** in a method are visible only within the same method invocation (so each time foo() is invoked, new local variables are used).

Values can be passed indirectly by storing them in instance or class variables (global variables), but that's ugly and error prone. The better variant is to **pass the values as method arguments**, this works well with multiple invocations and also multiple Threads, and removes the side effects you'd have when passing values using global variables.

In your example, just pass the value of a to your method:

```
public mainclass extends otherclass {
      @override 
      otherclass.method {
             // where my application starts
             int a=7;
             roll(a);
      }

      void roll(int funcVar){
          // funcVar is whatever value was passed, here: 7
          return;
      {
}
```

Comment: When setting the on click listener for a view in an android application you override and anonymously instantiated object of the View super class with your view.  Therefore as this becomes an innerclass, it is not allowed to access non final variables, and thus you are not able to pass variables (non final anyway) to the function you assign to the click event.